# Javascript window.frame.location on page load

Tags: javascript, location, frame, onload, frameset

I'm trying to change the location of an adjacent frame on page load with Javascript.

I have a page with a frameset:

```
<html lang="en">
<HEAD>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm() {
  //Code to execute before page close
  return '[close message]';
}
window.onbeforeunload=confirm;
</script>

<frameset cols="30%, 70%" FRAMEBORDER=NO FRAMESPACING=0 BORDER=0>

<frame name="leftFrame" src="control.php" scrolling="no">
<frame name="right" id="right" src="q.php">
</frameset>
</head>
</html>
```

My leftFrame is control.php, which has a form whose action is also control.php:

```
<!-- sample form on control.php -->
<form method="post" action="control.php">
<input ../>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The idea is that every time the form is submitted, the right frame is supposed to reload back to q.php:

```
<script language="javascript">
function refresh() {
    parent.right.location.href ="q.php";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="refresh();">
```

But this is not working. The right frame stays as is and doesn't change back to q.php. in other words `refresh()` isn't working.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `onload` i used `onsubmit`. my guess is that it wasn't working `onload` because the page was already loaded.

Answer (score -1):

havent seen frames used in a long time,

i think the issue is the way you are calling the frame, try

```
top.frames["right"].location.href="q.php";
```